# Polymer via Cordova on Android: Access to native Back and Menu buttons?

Tags: android, cordova, polymer

Is it possible to hook into Android's native tray buttons?  I'd like to handle the Back button even myself, as well as set up and capture events from a native Menu (the vertical three-dots).  The information I've found for native Menus is very out of date (phonegap cerca 2012) and isn't relevant anymore. Are there any modern examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to use the standard Cordova events for this no? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton